# how to get terragrunt to read tfvars files into dependent modules

Tags: terraform, hcl, terragrunt, terraform-template-file

Anyone know how to get terragrunt to read tfvars files into dependent modules? If I declare all my tfvars as inputs in my root terragrunt.hcl, everything works fine, but of course then I can’t customize them by environment. I tried adding the `extra_arguments` block, but the variables aren’t declared in the root module. They’re declared in the dependent module and I don’t want to have to declare them in both places.

Here’s my setup:

```golang
// terraform/terragrunt.hcl

terraform {
  extra_arguments "common_vars" {
    commands = ["plan", "apply"]
    arguments = [
      "-var-file=${find_in_parent_folders("account.tfvars")}",
      "-var-file=./terraform.tfvars"
    ]
  }
}

locals {
  environment_vars = read_terragrunt_config(find_in_parent_folders("account.hcl"))
  bucket = local.environment_vars.locals.bucket
}

remote_state {
  backend = "s3"
  generate = {
    path      = "backend.tf"
    if_exists = "overwrite_terragrunt"
  }

  config = {
    key    = "${path_relative_to_include()}/terraform.tfstate"
    region = "us-east-1"
    bucket = local.bucket
  }
}

dependencies {
  paths = ["../../../shared/services", "../../../shared/core"]
}
```

```golang
// terraform/accounts/dev/account.tfvars

aws_region = "us-east-1"
```

```golang
// terraform/accounts/dev/william/terraform.tfvars

aws_vpc_cidr = "10.1.0.0/16"
```

```golang
// terraform/accounts/dev/william/terragrunt.hcl

include {
  path = find_in_parent_folders()
}
```

This doesn't work because the variable values don't actually get passed to the dependent modules. I got this back when I tried to run a terragrunt plan:

```py
''' TERMINAL OUTPUT

$ terragrunt plan
No changes. Infrastructure is up-to-date.

This means that Terraform did not detect any differences between your
configuration and real physical resources that exist. As a result, no
actions need to be performed.

Warning: Value for undeclared variable
The root module does not declare a variable named
"aws_region" but a value was found in file
"/Users/williamjeffries/code/parachute/infrastructure/terraform/accounts/dev/account.tfvars".

To use this value, add a "variable" block to the configuration.
Using a variables file to set an undeclared variable is deprecated and will
become an error in a future release. If you wish to provide certain "global"
settings to all configurations in your organization, use TF_VAR_...
environment variables to set these instead.
```

Actually there were 26 such warnings, I’ve only pasted in one here but you get the idea. It seems like there should be some way to solve this with a terragrunt `generate` block but I'm not sure how. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I have been following the [documentation here](https://terragrunt.gruntwork.io/docs/features/keep-your-terraform-code-dry/) where it suggested to have directory structure:

```
live
├── prod
│   ├── app
│   │   └── terragrunt.hcl
│   ├── mysql
│   │   └── terragrunt.hcl
│   └── vpc
│       └── terragrunt.hcl
├── qa
│   ├── app
│   │   └── terragrunt.hcl
etc...
```

and

```
# content of qa/app/terragrunt.hcl
terraform {
  # Deploy version v0.0.3 in qa
  source = "git::git@github.com:foo/modules.git//app?ref=v0.0.3"
}

inputs = {
  # tfvars for qa
  instance_count = 3
  instance_type  = "t2.micro"
}
```

and

```
# content of prod/app/terragrunt.hcl
terraform {
  # Deploy version v0.0.3 in prod
  source = "git::git@github.com:foo/modules.git//app?ref=v0.0.3"
}

inputs = {
  # tfvars for prod
  instance_count = 20
  instance_type  = "t2.2xlarge"
}
```

and then the source could be within the same git repo., i.e: just app directory.  You could then customize module app by different environment (and even different versions in different environments)